# How do cost reducers affect costs that include XX?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

How does [Mass Manipulation](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mass%20Manipulation) work with [Hinata, Dawn-Crowned](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hinata%2C%20Dawn-Crowned)? How does the mana reducing ability interact with the XXUUUU mana cost?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cost reduction is applied to the total cost, which is determined by substituting your choice of X into the cost on the card.

In the case of Mass Manipulation and Hinata, Dawn-Crowned, you would first choose a value N for X and N targets. Then Hinata's ability would reduce the cost by {N} because the spell has N targets. The result is that the spell would cost {N}{U}{U}{U}{U}.

The steps for casting a spell are described in [rules section 601.2](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Casting_spells). Choosing the value of X happens in step 601.2b, choosing targets happens in step 601.2c, and calculating the total cost happens in step 601.2f.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, Hinita would basically remove one of the X's If you choose one target the total cost is 2UUUU which gets reduced to 1UUUU because of the one target.

If X is equal to 2 then the total cost is 4UUUU that then gets reduced back down to 2UUUU because of the two targets